# When signing to my primary Gmail account, it signs me automatically in to my secondary Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have two Gmail accounts: firstname.lastname@gmail.com and firstnamelastname@gmail.com (second one does not have a dot). When I want to sign in to second one, the Gmail signs me into first one. How to stop that please?

Answer (score 1):

Basically both email addresses are same because [Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20someone%20accidentally%20adds%20dots,john.smith%40gmail.com).

> If someone accidentally adds dots to your address when emailing you, you'll still get that email. For example, if your email is **johnsmith@gmail.com**, you own all dotted versions of your address:
>
> - **john.smith@gmail.com**
> - **jo.hn.sm.ith@gmail.com**
> - **j.o.h.n.s.m.i.t.h@gmail.com**
>
> **Note:** If you use Gmail through work, school, or other organization (like yourdomain.com or yourschool.edu), dots do change your address. To change the dots in your username, contact your [admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960).

Comment: Thank you so much!